# How can I give one account to all calendars in Microsoft Exchange server 2007

Tags: permissions, exchange-server, calendar

I have the ambition to create a Windows Desktop Application which can view all agendas of my coworkers. Extracting data from my own personal calendar is quite easy. I wonder if there is a permission which will grant me access to all calendars of coworkers. Some kind of super user. I've looked around a lot but still don't have a straight answer.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version of MS Exchange you use.  If you are a member of the Exchange Administrators Group in Active Directory, and running Exchange 2010 or later you can use Powershell to grant permissions.

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335061(v=exchg.150).aspx

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission cmdlet
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298062(v=exchg.150).aspx

For example:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "lori.petty@tankgirl.com:\Calendar" -user "JetGirl@tankgirl.com" -AccessRights Reviewer
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "lori.petty@tankgirl.com:\Calendar" //check that it worked
```

To do it in batch:

```
Get-Mailbox | ForEach-Object {Add-MailboxFolderPermission $_":\Calendar" -User "Your Name Here" -AccessRights Reviewer}
```

You can add filters to above to manage whether or not they're a resource mailbox or a regular user, check group membership, etc.  If you're comfortable coding, you get the idea.  Even better would be to create an account just for your application and add permissions to it rather than using your own.  Decouple yourself from the application.

If you are using earlier versions of Exchange, then the bad news is that you'll need to log on as the user by adding their account in outlook, using your username and password - I believe on Exchange 2007 you had to use the full Outlook client - OWA won't work ( double-check this because my experience is with the Light version of Outlook Web Access ).

At that point you'll have to delegate calendar permissions to the user you intend to use ( or yourself ) and then log out and remove the mailbox from your Outlook profile.  Requires a restart of Outlook every time.

You'll also need to be delegated access to that mailbox - which you can do using Powershell even in earlier versions of Exchange ( Add-MailboxPermission/Get-MailboxPermission, etc... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff381460.aspx )